# .NET Async IO associated with calling Sleep on response handler

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I have a piece of code (on a server) that uses async method to receive data on sockets like this:

```
asyncRes = connectionSocket.BeginReceive(receiveBuffer, 0, RECEIVING_BUFFER_SIZE,
    SocketFlags.None, out error, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveDataDone), null);
```

In the handler (ReceiveDataDone) of the socket there are cases where Thread.Sleep(X) is used in order to wait for other things(questionable implementation indeed). I know this is a questionable design but I wonder if making such kind of code could explain an explosion of threads created in my application because of the other pending sockets in the server that have their ReceiveDataDone called. (when many connections are handled by the server the number of threads created figuratively explodes). I wonder how `BeginReceive`  method on .NET sockets work, that could explain the huge number of threads I see.

Comment: @nos Yes, I corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely should not perform any kind of blocking action in APM callbacks. These are run in the ThreadPool. The ThreadPool is designed for the invocation of short-lived tasks. If you block (or take a long time to execute) you are tying up (a finite number of) threads and causing ThreadPool starvation. Because the ThreadPool does not spin up extra threads easily (in fact, it's quite slow to start extra threads), you're bottlenecking on the timing that controls how quickly the ThreadPool is allowed to spin up new threads.

Despite answering a different question, this answer I provided a while back explains the same issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733226/14357

Comment: I've removed the Sleep from the callback and things improved seriously. It was creating more then 900 threads at a point (on an 8 hw threads machine) and now it doesn't grow more than 70 :-)

Comment: So it seems that  the blocking/wait behavior determines thread pool to create huge amounts of additional threads

Comment: Indeed, but it will do so quite slowly (in the hope that you're going to stop abusing it soon), so your app is going to be slow at responding to increased load.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `Thread.sleep` for waiting in ThreadPool Threads this causes the Thread to be blocked and It will not accept any further workitems for the time it is blocked.

You can use [TimerCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback.aspx) for such a use case. It will let the `ThreadPool` schedule other work on the waiting thread in the meantime.