# ASP.NET MVC 4 asyncronous database call: never returns the HTTP response

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I tried to make an async database call to SQL Server and use it along with new ASP.NET MVC 4 async features but it strangely does not return at all. I debugged the code, works nicely but somehow the HTTP request hangs open forever.

Here is what I did:

This is the database call method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Car>> GetCarsAsync() {

    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CarGalleryConnStr"].ConnectionString;
    var asyncConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString) {
        AsynchronousProcessing = true
    }.ToString();

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(asyncConnectionString)) {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand()) {

            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = selectStatement;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync()) {

                return reader.Select(r => carBuilder(r)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `Select` method on `SqlDataReader` is an extension method which I implemented. `carBuilder` private method just returns back an instance of `Car` class.

This is the controller class:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    private readonly GalleryContext ctx = new GalleryContext();

    public async Task<ViewResult> IndexAsync() {

        return View("Index", await ctx.GetCarsAsync());
    }
}
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8478691/27535 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1733027/27535

Comment: @gbn so, do you think the implementation is wrong or pointless? Can u also have a look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15991/checking-if-the-query-is-made-async-or-sync-on-sql-server-2008-r2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in MVC 4 Beta that causes a hang when you return an async `Task` that completes really quickly.

The workaround to it is to add the following as the first line of your action method:

```
await Task.Yield();
```

Could you see if that fixes it?

More info here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/22

Answer (score 3):

Your controller still needs to derive from [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) (see [Exercise 4: Using Asynchronous Controllers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh553504)), but now you need to write less code to achieve the same result with `Task<T>`.

So this should work:

```
public class HomeController : AsyncController {

    private readonly GalleryContext ctx = new GalleryContext();

    public async Task<ViewResult> IndexAsync() {

        return View("Index", await ctx.GetCarsAsync());
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it has to. I have several other Task-based async actions which consumes web services asynchronously and the controller for those derived from `Controller` class.  Let me try, though.

Comment: ah, bummer! It worked but it is strange because as I said, I have several other Task-based async actions which consumes web services asynchronously and the controller for those derived from Controller class.

Comment: I don't know what is causing the difference... but according to the sample and the other articles online, you should derive from `AsyncController`.

Comment: Hi, please see the @marcind's answer. That is the solution.